# How to link external library in Clion/Cmake?

Tags: c, cmake, clion

I am new to Cmake, and I am having trouble linking an external library (libtiff). I have installed libtiff and it is in my `/usr/local/include`. Then I used `include_directories()` and `target_linked_libraries()` in my Cmake. However, it still gives me

```
ld: library not found for -ltiff
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tiffio.h"

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(test2 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

include_directories(/usr/local/include)

add_executable(test2 main.c)

target_link_libraries(test2 tiff)
```

I would really appreciate if you can help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<new_lib_directory>`

Comment: Should <new_lib_directory> be usr/local/include or usr/local/lib? Where do I add it to? Thanks! @MiguelÁngelRetamozoSanchez.

Comment: Use the [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) to "find" it. CMake add the correct flags when using the library so it can be linked with and also used when running (for dynamic libraries).

Comment: Note that using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is [not always recommended](https://www.hpc.dtu.dk/?page_id=1180).

Comment: Frankly I don't care if another question has some answers that may apply here. It is not a duplicate as it is not the same question and none of those answers apply to CLION.

Answer (score 1):

Import  library instead of link directory.

```
# Your-external "mylib", add GLOBAL if the imported library is located in directories above the current.
    add_library( mylib SHARED IMPORTED )
    # You can define two import-locations: one for debug and one for release.
    set_target_properties( mylib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/res/mylib.so )
```

Link the library like this

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(GLBall mylib)
```

see this link for import libaray  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:add_library